# Upgrade protobuf leeds to warning with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

Here is what I found out so far. Upgrading protobuf leads to this:

```
$ pip3 install --upgrade protobuf
Collecting protobuf
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/18/e7/785830a65d1f1faba7dccfa8314f7afded1db8cc2860218226ba4b3f6150/protobuf-3.6.1-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from protobuf) (40.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six>=1.9 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from protobuf) (1.11.0)
tensorflow 0.12.0 has requirement protobuf==3.1.0, but you'll have protobuf 3.6.1 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: protobuf
  Found existing installation: protobuf 3.1.0
    Uninstalling protobuf-3.1.0:
      Successfully uninstalled protobuf-3.1.0
Successfully installed protobuf-3.6.1
```

In short: `tensorflow 0.12.0 has requirement protobuf==3.1.0`.
Why does the newest tensorflow version needs and old protobuf version?

But this is even weirder:

```
$ pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
...
tensorboard 1.12.0 has requirement protobuf>=3.4.0
```

Is my conclusion correct? tensorflow and tensorboard need different versions of protobuf? how? what am I missing out?

I found a similar bug but I didn't understand it completely. Something with Mac Operation System and cpython. Link to issue: https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/681

I use macOS and I've installed python with Homebrew.

Will it help me to install an older python version?

I am searching for an explanation and solutions. 
Thank you

Comment: Don't confuse TensorFlow 0.12.0 with TensorFlow 1.12.0. TensorFlow 0.12.0 is very old. TensorFlow 1.12.0 requires protobuf >=3.6.1

Comment: thanks. But how come pip cannot find 1.12.0 ? output: Collecting tensorflow==1.12.0
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.12.0 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.12.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Tensorflow doesn’t support the newest version of python. Pip cannot find the newest version of Tensorflow for python 3.7.